# Running a GitHub Actions step only if specific steps failed

Tags: github-actions

I’d like to run a step only if specific previous steps FAILED with Exit Code different from Zero.
I’ve tried the code below but it not working.
How can I do that?

```
- name: JobA
  id: seedBuild
  run: |
        echo "::set-output name=exit_code::$(echo -n "$?")"

- name: JobB
  id: allJobs
  run: |
        echo "::set-output name=exit_code::$(echo -n "$?")"

- name: Debug Job Failure
  run: |
        echo "******** Job Logs from ********"
  if: "${{ steps.seedBuild.outputs.exit_code != 0 || steps.allJobs.outputs.exit_code != 0 }}"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the step's outcome [`steps.<step_id>.outcome`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#steps-context):

code:

```
- name: JobA
  id: seedBuild
  run: |
        echo "failing on purpose"
        exit 1

- name: JobB
  id: allJobs
  run: |
        echo "::set-output name=exit_code::$(echo -n "$?")"

- name: Debug Job Failure
  run: |
        echo "******** Job Logs from ********"
  if: always() && (steps.seedBuild.outcome == 'failure' || steps.allJobs.outcome == 'failure')
```

Comment: If, like me, you wonder why the condition includes `always() &&`, you can find the explanation in [Status check functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions): *A default status check of success() is applied unless you include one of these functions.*. In other words, GitHub inserts `success() &&` unless you call `always()`, `canceled()`, or `failure()`.